# problem with data processing OracleDataReader (OracleRefCursor)

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

i need help, when i get the data of procedure BD (Oracle). I do not know how to deal with data type date time, int etc. I only know do with strings

```
public static Player_E getPlayer(string select)
    {
        Player_E player = new Player_E();
        DateTime? dateTime = new DateTime();

        conexion = bd.ConexionWithDB();

        orden.CommandText = "CONSULTAS.obtener_jugador";
        orden.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        orden.Parameters.Add("v_nombre", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 60).Value = select;
        orden.Parameters.Add("jugadores_dev", OracleDbType.RefCursor, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output);


        orden.Parameters.Add("c2blob", OracleDbType.Blob).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        orden.Connection = conexion;

        orden.ExecuteNonQuery();

        OracleDataReader dr = ((OracleRefCursor)orden.Parameters["jugadores_dev"].Value).GetDataReader();


        dr.Read();
        //tbNombre.Text = dr["c1"].ToString();


        OracleBlob blob = (OracleBlob)orden.Parameters["c2blob"].Value;

        byte[] filedata = null;
        if (blob.Length != 0)
        {
            filedata = new byte[blob.Length];

        }

        //these are attempts that I have been making

        //dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["d1"].ToString());
        //dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetOrdinal("d1").ToString());
        //dateTime = dr["d1"].ToString().Length > 0 ? DateTime.Parse(dr["d1"].ToString()) : DateTime.MinValue;

        //dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["d1"].ToString(),"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES"));


        player = new Player_E (dr["c1"].ToString(), dr["c2"].ToString(), dr["c3"].ToString(), dateTime, dr["c4"].ToString(), filedata);

        //dr.Dispose();


        //orden.Dispose();
        conexion.Close();
        return player;
    }
```

Here is the method where i call for the send the object Player with the values.

Edit: This is the Procedure:

PROCEDURE OBTENER_JUGADOR (v_nombre          VARCHAR2,
                               est_jugador   OUT estructura_devuelta,
                               C2BLOB        OUT BLOB)

```
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TMP_ESTRUCTURA (c1,
                                c2,
                                c3,
                                d1,
                                c4)
        SELECT NOMBRE,
               DIRECCION,
               PUESTO_HAB,
               FECHA_NAC,
               EQUIPO_JUGADOR
          FROM jugador
         WHERE nombre = v_nombre;


         SELECT FOTO_JUGADOR
         INTO C2BLOB
          FROM jugador
         WHERE nombre = v_nombre;


    OPEN est_jugador FOR SELECT * FROM TMP_ESTRUCTURA;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        raise_application_error (
            -20100,
            'El jugador ' || v_nombre || '  no existe' || SQLERRM);
END OBTENER_JUGADOR;
```

Thanks for all

Comment: If you are using the Microsoft Oracle client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2: `var dateTime = dr.GetDateTime(0);` assuming the ordinal output of the value is 0. If you are not sure get the ordinal position first using GetOrdinal

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment, i using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client; and i tried `dr.GetString(0);` all values is string, (0,1,2,3,4,5) all is string and value null. The structure is string,string,string,date,string,blob. and i get all this for procedure.

Comment: This type library also has `OracleDataReader.GetDateTime()` and `OracleDataReader.GetOracleDate()`, why are you not trying/using those?

Comment: I was used `while(dr.Read()) { name = dr.GetString(0); ... ... dateTime = dr.GetDateTime(0) }`  and the value is null but when i use with name = dr["c1"].ToString(); the value isn`t null

Comment: I've tried again in case I was wrong before and it's the same result. The error is -> the column have data null Unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll. the code is `jugador = new Jugador_E(dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1), dr.GetString(2), dr.GetDateTime(3), dr.GetString(4), filedata);`

Comment: In the end I solved it using a null control `if (dr["d1"].ToString().Equals("") || dr["d1"].ToString() == null)` Thanks for everything